# Simulate didSelectRowAtIndexPath with a UIButton in a customized UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview

I have a UIButton in a customized UITableViewCell, which subclassing UITableViewCell.

The UIButton is IBOutlet-ed in IB, and IBAction-ed to a function:

```
- (IBAction)clickRead:(id)sender;
```

Now, when I click on the button, the button has no response, since the function has nothing inside. What should I write in the function so that the UIButton can simulate tableView's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function ( i.e. select the table cell ) ?

Comment: did you mean when you click on a button of any row then that row should be selected ?

Comment: yes ! If the button on the row is clicked, the row should be selected & the function didSelectAtIndexPath should be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer might help: [hitting a next button for a UITableViewcell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188242/hitting-a-next-button-for-a-uitableviewcell)

You can call `UITableView selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` to visually select the row, but you will still have to manage any events for yourself: loading another view, calling `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, storyboard segues, etc.